# .htaccess rewrite optional trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have my website excluding the .html using the following code in .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

And this works great, but if I add a trailing slash I get a 404.

I'd like to have the option of having it work as it is now and also if I add a trailing slash at the end.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... so now when I add the trailing slash, it ignores my CSS distorting the page... if I take out the slash it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths for css/js/images. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can also try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Another quick question that you may be able to assist me with... i no longer am able to get my custom 404 page and now get a 500 internal server error. would you know how to add it back?

Comment: I added this: ErrorDocument 404 /oops.html  but I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error whenever I get a page that's not there

Comment: @anubhava in regexp pattern `^(.+?)/?$` why the first `?` (after + sign) is used here? What does it literly mean?

Comment: `?` is non-greedy or lazy quantifier that allows `.+` to stop matching before last optional `/`

Comment: @anubhava sorry but couldn't get. But I see if i don't use `?` after `+` then the url `http://www.example.com/sample/` doesn't work.

Comment: Please follow some regex tutorial like https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html to get clarity.